# Is Using Javascript inside a jQuery function is a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know basics of both jQuery and JavaScript.I would like to follow a good coding practice. Is using JavaScript inside a jQuery function is a bad practice?

**For exapmle:**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#dqualification').change(function() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Resolve following errors"; 
    });
});
```

Comment: yes it is bad practice, never mix the two languages under threat of hellfire and damnation ... jQuery is written in a programming language called javascript ... so, take the opening sentence as sarcasm

Comment: @JordiCastilla : Thanks  for the clarification .So I can mix both freely .Don't worry I wont do that until it is necessary :)

Comment: if you do mix them, make sure you are wearing appropriate hazmat suit - level 4 at least ... /sarcasm

Comment: jQuery is a Javascript [Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)). For performance sometimes you coud need use javascript directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, its fine, and it's done all the time.

Consider:

```
$("#myDiv").on("click", function(){
    var a = this;
});
```

The line `var a = this;` is pure JavaScript. There is no "jQuery Version" of `var a = this;`.

jQuery provides convenient ways of doing things in JavaScript that might be difficult to write and code yourself in pure JavaScript. *It doesn't replace JavaScript, it just 'adds to it'.*

Remember, jQuery is just a JavaScript library. So everything ends up as JavaScript at the end of the day.

Comment: I think this is the best answer :)

Comment: But, but, what about `var $a = $(this)`? :-P

Answer (score 2):

It is not directly *bad practice*, it is more a bit inconsistend. Both is `javascript`. But why would you do things like in your example? If you have jQuery available, you could use it!

```
$(function() {
    $('#dqualification').change(function() {
        $("#demo").html("Resolve following errors");
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes , If you have jQuery available, I am using that only .This one I gave for exmple . But in some situations I supposed to use javascript. Is that a bad practice ?

Comment: jQuery **is** javascript, did you not get that?

Comment: Even if jQuery is available you should use pure Javascript over jQuery, because it is faster.

Comment: Yes I know :) I learned from W3 schools jQuery is a JavaScript Library.
jQuery greatly simplifies JavaScript programming. :) But mixing of that is Okay or not ? Some of my friends told it is not good

Comment: No jQuery is Javascript. If you call a jQuery function it is a shorthand for a Javascript implementation

Comment: jQuery is a library written in javascript - it is not a separate language, therefore, any code inside a jQuery function is javascript

Comment: @JordiCastilla as far as I know, what you are saying is wrong!

Comment: @Sree - mixing javascript and jquery is like mixing water at 20 degrees and water at 21 degrees ... it's all water ... perhaps you mean directly using DOM methods vs the jQuery wrappers on DOM methods?

Comment: @Sree, if someone told you it is *bad practice*, then they should give you examples why it is! It's a bit unconventional, to write it like in your entering example, but it's not forbidden nor wrong!

Comment: @JaromandaX : That's a great reply and a great example too . Thanks :)